# Let us define a custom link when uploading images

Tags: feature-request, editor, uploader

When I upload an image via the editor dialog, it automatically links back to itself.

I would like the option to specify custom URL instead, which it would link to, e.g. by adding a textbox in the image upload dialog.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can provide a custom image source URL and a custom link URL as well.

The generated image markdown actually consists of two parts: The image itself and the link. Usually the same URL is used for both, but you can specify two separate URLs if you want:

```
[![description][1]][2]

  [1]: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/bb/First_abstract_watercolor_kandinsky_1910.jpg
  [2]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_art
```

where `[1]` is the URL for the image and `[2]` for the link.

[image: description]

Comment: [Kandinsky's first abstract watercolor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kandinsky%27s_first_abstract_watercolor)